# Hide Facebook friend's events from calendar

Tags: calendar, facebook

I added my Facebook account to the calendar to sync up my Facebook friend's birthdays in my calendar. But along with the birthdays, few useless events also got added automatically. Like if my friend who is a football fan, is attending a Football match somewhere, that event is displaying in "MY CALENDAR". 
It is very annoying to see my friend's events in my calendar. How do I stop that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has your friend invited you to the event? I've never seen my friends' events in my calendar, only when they've invited me too. For these events you need to remove the event by going to the event's facebook page, scrolling all the way down and clicking the "Remove from My events" link in the footer. Facebook won't sync the RSVP info for some reason, so "Hide declined events" in the calendar options won't hide events that you're not attending (which is very annoying by the way).

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this requires you to go onto the web version of facebook. From the newsfeed page, select 'events' from the column on the left. On the events page, select list and press the cross in the right hand corner of the event you want removed. Then on your phone, open calendar and press the menu button, select sync and it should remove the event. For some reason, facebook doesn't seem to inform your calendar of declined events, so removal is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the calendar app on your phone, you may be able to do this easily. I'm using a Samsung Captivate with Froyo, and can hide Facebook events by doing the following:

1. Open `Calendar`
2. `Menu` > `More` > `Settings`
3. `Calendars`
4. Check on or off the various calendars you want to display. On mine i have **Phone**, **Gmail** and **Facebook**. Unchecking the **Facebook** one removes these events from my calendar.

In addition to which phone and calendaring app you use, this may also be affected by how you sync your Facebook calendar, via the official Facebook app or via some other 'social' software.

If you give details about your phone, calendar and social software being used, someone may be able to give more detailed and/or directly applicable help.

Comment: Note that this hides all events from Facebook, including your own.

Comment: Good point to make, should be clear about that. So while this would work, it wouldn't be the ideal solution if you do have your own events in Facebook that you want to see in your Android calendar.